# A fever medicine cures 75% persons.Three persons suffering from fever used it .The probability that all three persons will be benefitted from it,is

Tags: probability

So I tried to analyse the question but failed to either identify either the sample space or the experiment.But I got the hint that all three will be independent and equally likely.will anyone guide me from here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability that the medicine cures someone is assumed to be independent on if it cures others. The probability that person one gets cured is $\frac{3}{4}$. The probability that two people get cured is $\frac{3}{4}^2$. The probability that three people get cured is $\frac{3}{4}^3 = .422$.

The sample space is all the possible events that $can$ happen and the event space is all the events in which the criterion is satisfied. In this case, there is only one event satisfying it. Let $1$ denote someone being cured, and let $0$ denote someone not being cured. Then the sample space is $100$, $010$, $001$, $101$, $110$, $011$, $111$, $000$. Note that there are $2^3$ possibilities. Only one of these meet the requirement that all $3$ are cured. Namely, $111$. However you cannot say the answer is $\frac{1}{8}$ because these occur with different probabilities.

A more interesting question would be something like:

$10$ people suffering from a fever are given medication. What is the probability that $7$ people are cured. In this case, we have a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) giving

$${10\choose{7}} \cdot \frac{3}{4}^7 \cdot \frac{1}{4}^3$$

Comment: How did u get that 3/4 probability and can u tell me what the sample space is here?

Comment: $\frac{3}{4}$ is $75$% expressed as a fraction. This is the same as the probability that someone gets cured. Probabilities are always between 0 and 1.

Comment: Got that but can we define sample space here or  will it be unknowwn?

Comment: The binomial distribution seems to be out of the scope of what you have learned thus far so ignore that unless you're interested.

Comment: Will update answer in a few minutes explaining that.

Comment: So sample space is combination of curing and non-curing of these three persons in any order.Thanx for your help!

Comment: Yep, in other words, it's all the ways in which the curing of $3$ people can turn out. Note that the probabilities of all the possibilities in the sample space should sum to $1$ but do not make the mistake of assuming all $8$ of these occur with probability $\frac{1}{8}$.

Comment: but why aren't  all the probabilities equally likelly?

Comment: Consider 3 people all not getting cured. The probability that one person does not get cured is $1-\frac{3}{4}$ or $25$% so the probability that all $3$ do not get cured is $\frac{1}{4}^3$

Comment: Also consider the case where the first person gets cured, the second person does not get cured, and third person gets cured. We would have $\frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{3}{4}$. Do you see why?

Comment: Thanx ,I got it now